# Python 3D Array Indexing

Tags: python, numpy

I am confused by the following.

```
B = np.array([[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]])
print(B[0,1,0])
```

This returns the value of 3. But my expectation is that it should return 2 because it is the first row, second column, first "page".

Furthermore, I am confusing because I thought python by default was row-major indexing. So if I did `np.ravel(B)` my expectation is that it should read out the numbers as `1 5 2 6 3 7 4 8` (last index, the "page", varies fastest). But instead when I do this I get back `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like in mathematics, you start with the inner most `parenthesis or brackets.`.

```
B = np.array([[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]])
print(B[0])
# > [[1 2]
#    [3 4]]

print(B[0][1])
# > [3 4]

print(B[0][1][0])
# > 3
```

In 2 dimensions or more:

- the last dimension `-1` is the one for the columns.
- the dimension before it `-2` is the one for the rows.

In 3 dimensions or more, the dimension `-3` can be thought as another sheet or some kind of stacked layers.

Above 3D, it stops making sense, then we'd better remind the `innermost is first` rule as universal.

Comment: Hm - so here the columns are the last index, which would explain the sequence that `ravel` spits out. That is so unintuitive to me. I would have expected the "pages"/depth dimension to vary the fastest since it is what I perceive as the last index.

Comment: In `numpy` the leading/first dimension is outermost, slowest.  Trailing/last is inner, and fastest varying.  The default indexing of the array is the same order as indexing the nest list you used to create it.

Comment: I see what you mean. But would it make sense to call B[0] and have [[1 ,2], [5, 6]] ? It would break the parenthesis, kind of.

Comment: I understand now - Thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

The last index is changing the fastest. I think that you have the first and last indexes mixed up.

Comment: Right. So to me the last index should be the pages/depth of the matrix and the first index should be the rows. Just my wrong initial perception I guess.